# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: raspbian, dpkg

Recently, I tried to install some software for raspbian. But after I type `sudo apt-get install upgrade`, I got this:

```
debconf: Perl may be unconfigured (Can't locate strict.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at (eval 1) line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 1) line 2.
) -- aborting
(Reading database ... 100033 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing squeak-vm ...
Can't locate File/Glob.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/sbin/update-mime line 76.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/sbin/update-mime line 76.
dpkg: error processing squeak-vm (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 squeak-vm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

which made me unable to continue, I was confused. I don't know what the problem is,
can anyone help me figure out this problem and help me solve it? thanks in advance!
I tried `dpkg --configure -a` and got this

```
Setting up qbittorrent (2.9.8-1) ...
Can't locate File/Glob.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/sbin/update-mime line 76.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/sbin/update-mime line 76.
dpkg: error processing qbittorrent (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up man-db (2.6.2-1) ...
Can't locate strict.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/share/debconf/frontend line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/debconf/frontend line 5.
dpkg: error processing man-db (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up mime-support (3.52-1+deb7u1) ...
Can't locate File/Glob.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/sbin/update-mime line 76.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/sbin/update-mime line 76.
dpkg: error processing mime-support (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for menu ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 qbittorrent
 man-db
 mime-support
```

Comment: have you tried "dpkg --configure -a"? taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042102/apt-get-returns-error-debconf-perl-may-be-unconfigured-how-do-i-actually-un

Comment: `apt-get install upgrade`? Well, this command wold try to install packet called `upgrade`. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716918/cant-locate-file-glob-pm-in-inc-inc-contains-d-tools-lib-at-directory-p) about the particular "can't locate *.pm" errors. 
It seems to me you have some issue related to your perl installation. If the above question does not resolve your issue, have you tried the following?:

- Running `sudo apt-get update`, prior to attempting the upgrade
- `sudo apt-get remove perl`, followed by `sudo apt-get install perl` (or `sudo apt-get install --reinstall perl` if you prefer)

Also, as pointed out in the comments, "`sudo apt-get install upgrade`" seems suspicious, are you trying to upgrade the system? If so, use `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: thank you for your answer, however, I have installed the OS again.