# Cannot install docker on OS Lite (32 or 64bit) - E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, docker

I am trying to install docker and have tried in a couple different ways this far.
I am starting out with a brand new installation of Raspberry Pi OS **Lite** - Debian Bullseye. I have tried these steps with both 32 bit and 64 bit versions of the OS. I am using a raspberry pi 3b if that matters.

After the initial flashing of the SD card I run `apt update` and `apt upgrade`, I also expand the filesystem, adjust the hostname and change the standard password - that's all.
Then I move onto trying to install [docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/#install-using-the-convenience-script). As mentioned on their site, I should be using their *convenience script*:

```
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
DRY_RUN=1 sudo sh ./get-docker.sh
```

Executing these commands returns the following error:

```
# Executing docker install script, commit: 4f282167c425347a931ccfd95cc91fab041d414f
+ sh -c apt-get update -qq >/dev/null
+ sh -c DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y -qq apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl >/dev/null
+ sh -c mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings && chmod -R 0755 /etc/apt/keyrings
+ sh -c curl -fsSL "https://download.docker.com/linux/raspbian/gpg" | gpg --dearmor --yes -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
+ sh -c chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
+ sh -c echo "deb [arch=armhf signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/raspbian bullseye stable" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
+ sh -c apt-get update -qq >/dev/null
+ sh -c DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y -qq --no-install-recommends docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin >/dev/null
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried finding some resolution to this error message but I was not able to figure anything out. What are some next steps I could try in installing `docker` and and `docker-compose` onto my raspberry pi?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Is the error the same when you use 64bit?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It is the exact same error.

Comment: by the way, the instructions are flawed, since this is NOT doing a dry run, it's actually attempting to install ... to do an actual dry run run `sudo sh ./get-docker.sh --dry-run` - this will show everything it wants to do

Comment: having said that, the last two commands that would be executed are basically `apt install --no-install-recommends docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin` and `apt install docker-ce-rootless-extras` - what happens if you do that - running it manually like that, you'll see the error you are getting rather than just getting the error code

Comment: Have you tried a search engine? Try https://www.tecmint.com/sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26841/e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1)

Comment: Thank you for your comments @JaromandaX and @MatsK! I didn't know that DRY_RUN didn't actually do a dry run... That was the issue! I had to remove docker and then the installation worked without any issues. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that running `DRY_RUN=1 sudo sh ./get-docker.sh` does not actually perform just a dry run. So whenever I ran this command, some docker parts where already installed, failing the installation on the second run, without `DRY_RUN`.

I had to uninstall docker using

```
sudo apt-get purge docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin docker-ce-rootless-extras
```

After that the installation worked without any issues using:

```
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
sudo sh ./get-docker.sh
```